# Final keyword in java allowing changes in a method

Tags: java

I was playing around with some java to get a better feel for scopes. I wrote the following piece of code:

```
public class Scope {

    static int [] arr = { 10 };
    static final int num = 5;

    public static void manipulate(int[] arr, int num) {
        num = arr[0] + 10;
        arr[0] = num;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        manipulate(arr, num);
        System.out.println("arr[0] = "+ arr[0]);
        System.out.println("num = "+num);
    }  
}
```

Even though num is declared as static and final I am able to change its value inside the manipulate method. Just looking for some clarification on this as I did not think I would be able to change this.

Comment: Java is pass by value, but Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Object references are passed by value.

Comment: @manouti: Yes, the object is not the same. You cannot pass in an object and set it to another object expecting the object outside the method to change. You can mutate the object using mutators.

Comment: Change your method to `public static void manipulate(int[] arr, final int num)` to see, that changing the value of an `final` variable is not possible. The current answers are showing you, why you can change `num`.

Comment: Try `this.num = arr[0] + 10;` it won't compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't changing the `static final` `num` variable; you are changing the local copy of it in `manipulate`'s `num` parameter local variable.  When you print `num` back in `main`, it will still be `5`.

Answer (score 6):

You are manipulating the method argument, not the static field. The argument is `hiding` the static field.

Answer (score 4):

You have two num defined in your code.
First one is, this one never changed

```
   static final int num = 5;
```

Second one is: this second on is changed by your code

```
   public static void manipulate(int[] arr, int num)
```

You are passing first one into second num, by Java is pass by value, your first num is not changed by this passing.